# Create a symbolic link named long_file pointing to the largest file in the current directory

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal

I know how to create a symbolic link but I don't kow how to get largetst file in current directory. Please, help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the following command:

```bash
find /path/to/dir-with-big-file/ -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'ln -sf % /path/to/symlink'
```

which breaks down as follows:

- `find /path/to/dir-with-big-file/ -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n"` - find files and print `%s` files size and `%p` name.
- `sort -n -r | head -n 1` - sort in reverse order and get the first (i.e. biggest) one
- `awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I % sh -c  'ln -sf % /path/to/symlink'` - extract full file name and create or update a symlink (e.g. in you case long_file)

Comment: Nice approach with Schwartzian transform, but you'll need to consider the case
the filepath contains whitespace characters. For instance, it will be better to say
`cut -f2-` rather than `awk '{print $2}'`.